# instrument A B vs. instrument A with B

Tags: word-meaning, transitivity

Source: [Understanding and Using C Pointers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1449344186) by Richard M. Reese (2013)

Example:

> The Mudflap Libraries provide a similar capability for the GCC compiler. Its runtime library supports the detection of memory leaks, among other things. This detection is accomplished by **instrumenting the pointer dereferencing operations**.

Is it correct to say it like that? Can we really say *instrument A B* to mean that we are going to equip A with B?

Comment: No. *Instrument* will not bear that meaning. I suggest *implementing*, but I haven't been a programmer for 25 years, so my knowledge of C-chic is not uptodate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't say ***equip*** A with B but *A **uses** what B has for his purpose*.

See [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/instrument) (First block, 5.):

> One used by another to accomplish a purpose; a dupe.

So in your example the detection works by using (existing) pointer dereferencing operations.

Comment: And that use is a noun, not a verb. (There are a couple verbs way down on the page, but they're rare and specialized.)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

> *...supports education among...*  This education is strengthened by **performing the language enhancing exercises**.

I tried constructing it in the same pattern as the sentence about which you are asking.

**Instrumenting** is a gerund from the verb "*instrument*" meaning "*supply with additional mechanisms for easy interaction with tools*".

**Pointer dereferencing operations** are *operations* that involve *dereferencing of pointers*.

So, the entire highlighted fragment is "doing the what doing what", where the "what doing what" is an adjective-noun phrase, and "pointer dereferencing" is the adjective.